# Field jobBuilderFactory in com.* required a bean of type 'JobBuilderFactory' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

```
package com.batch.springBatch.config;

import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.item.data.RepositoryItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.LineMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

import com.batch.springBatch.entity.Employee;
import com.batch.springBatch.repository.EmployeRespository;


@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {

    @Value("${app.batch.file.name}")
    private String fileName;

    @Value("${app.batch.file.isHeader}")
    private String isHeaderPresent;

    @Value("${app.batch.file.headers.include}")
    private String[] fieldNames;

    @Value("${app.batch.file.headers.index}")
    private int[] fieldIndex;

    @Autowired
    private EmployeRespository employeRespository;

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<Employee> reader() {
        
        FlatFileItemReader<Employee> dataReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        dataReader.setResource(new ClassPathResource(fileName));
        dataReader.setLineMapper(getLineMapper());
        if (isHeaderPresent.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
            dataReader.setLinesToSkip(1);// skipping Header
        }
        return dataReader;
    }

    @Bean
    public LineMapper<Employee> getLineMapper() {

        DefaultLineMapper<Employee> dataLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();

        DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        lineTokenizer.setDelimiter(",");
        // lineTokenizer.setStrict(true);//by default it is true
        lineTokenizer.setNames(fieldNames);
        lineTokenizer.setIncludedFields(fieldIndex);

        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Employee> fieldSetter = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
        fieldSetter.setTargetType(Employee.class);

        dataLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
        dataLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetter);

        return dataLineMapper;
    }

    @Bean
    public EmployeItemProcessor processor() {
        return new EmployeItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public RepositoryItemWriter<Employee> writer() {

        RepositoryItemWriter<Employee> dataWriter = new RepositoryItemWriter<>();
        dataWriter.setRepository(employeRespository);
        dataWriter.setMethodName("save");

        return dataWriter;
    }
}
```

```
package com.batch.springBatch.config;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.batch.springBatch.entity.Employee;

@Configuration
public class JobConfig {

    @Value("${app.batch.step.name}")
    private String batchStepName;

    @Value("${app.batch.chunk.size}")
    private int chunkSize;

    @Value("${app.batch.job.name}")
    private String jobName;

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    private ItemReader<Employee> reader;
    @Autowired
    private ItemProcessor<Employee, Employee> processor;
    @Autowired
    ItemWriter<Employee> writer;

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get(batchStepName).<Employee, Employee>chunk(chunkSize).reader(reader).processor(processor).writer(writer).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job runJob() {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get(jobName).flow(step1()).end().build();
    }

}
```

> Getting below error
>
> ```
> ***************************
> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
> ***************************
>
> Description:
>
> Field jobBuilderFactory in com.batch.springBatch.config.JobConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory' that could not be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>   - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory' in your configuration.
> ```

Hey developers. I am trying to read data from csv file and write it to mysql db but there are some issue in  my configuration file it seems. I tried giving @ComponentScan with my base config package name but didn't work. I thought it is because of the depreciated JobBuilderFactory & StepBuilderFactory but not very much clear on that. Could you please help me out of the scenario. My source code and console can be seen above.

Comment: why do you have more than one configuration class? Either way, try by adding the @EnableBatchProcessing annotation on that JobConfig class.

Comment: you are relying on Spring autoconfiguration to create those beans for you, but you are either not invoking autoconfiguration (with annotations as Stultuske mentioned) or you are overriding the configuration with your own @Configuration class.

Comment: Can you specify what spring boot and spring batch version are you using.
There is a migration guide that can help you here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide

Answer (score 0):

You should either move `@EnableBatchProcessing` on the `JobConfig` class, or add `@Import(BatchConfig.class)` on the `JobConfig` class.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change your spring `spring-boot-starter-parent` version.
I just changed spring boot parent version and it works fine for me
3.1.0 to 2.7.6.

Comment: He never mentioned what spring version is using, It would help to explain that the jobBuilderFactory has been deprecated in Spring 3 and that's why he has to downgrade his version, also spring 2.7.x is going to end it's support soon, so downgrading should not be the de-facto solution.